# Como criar array de objetos em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante em javascript e gostaria de saber se é possível criar array de objetos em javascript, se sim, como eu faço isso?
Sei que para criar um objeto eu preciso fazer o seguinte:

```
var Ponto = function (latitude, longitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

var ponto = new Ponto(80,50);
```

Minha intenção agora era criar um array de pontos para poder trabalhar com eles, isso é possível?
Agradeço desde já a colaboração de todos!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o `array.push()` para adicionar um item no fim do array.

```
var sample = new Array();
sample.push(new Object());
```

Pra fazer isso "n" vezes usando loop:

```
var n = 100;
var sample = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sample.push(new Object());
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho aqui. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

De modo básico a estrutura do array é essa:

```
var nomeDoArray ["Aqui","dentro","você","coloca","os","elementos","que","podem","ser","strings","como","você","está","vendo"];
```

Para visualizar os elementos do array separadamente basta imprimir no *console.log* como abaixo:

```
console.log(nomeDoArray[0]);
```

Os itens começam a ser numerados a partir do 0 no array, então, será mostrado o primeiro elemento do array nesse exemplo, que no caso é o elemento string *"Aqui"*.

Você só pode criar arrays com elementos do mesmo tipo, como exemplo, array de strings, de valores numéricos, etc. Não pode misturar os tipos.