# Lista do Model chega desatualiza no controller - Asp.Net mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc, model, viewmodel

Tenho uma ViewModel com duas listas de objetos.
A primeira delas é tem uma coluna editável, onde é possível alterar um valor numérico.

Apos alterar os valores da "ListaTipos" na view, a mesma não chega com os novos valores no controller.

```html
    public class ViewModelRetirada
    {
        ...
        public IEnumerable<Tipos> ListaTipos { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Terminais> ListaTerminais { get; set; }
    }
```

A Lista "ListaTipos" na View

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.ListaTipos) {
<tr class="table-active" align="center">
  <th scope="row">@item.IdIso</th>
  <td>@item.Reservados</td>
  <td>@item.QtdeRetirada</td>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.QtdeDisponivel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", @type="number"} })</td>
</tr>
}
```

Estou enviando o Model da seguinte forma:

```html
            $("#ExibeTerminais").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Retirada/ConfirmarRetirada',
                    type: "post",  
                    data: {tela: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))},                    
                    success: function (result) {                           
                        $("#DivListarTerminais").html(result)                        
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar recuperar a lista de terminais! \n Tente mais tarde")
                    }
                })
            })
```

Quando o Model chega no Controller, a ListaTipos não esta com os valores alterados na view.

Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir onde errei?
Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Jonas, tenta mudar esse trecho e veja se funciona: data: {tela: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ListaTipos))},

Comment: Olá Ajair, Obrigado pelo sua rápida sugestão! Fiz a alteração que vc sugereiu e pra isso tive que alterar meu controller para:
" public ActionResult ConfirmarRetirada(List<TiposContainer> tela) "
A lista chega ao controler mas com os valores desatualizados.

Será que esta correto a maneira como estou editando o valor na table ?!

Comment: Jonas, posta o código da sua controller, vai ficar mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Acho que não tenho privilégios pra editar minha pergunta, mas o código do controller esta neste link dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6mfv3vfiof5z0t/Controller.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Os valores estão indo pro model desatualizados pois na montagem do código da página pelo Razor está sendo passado model daquele momento (Com os valores iniciais). Para envia-los para o controller através do ajax, recomendo montar um objeto que vai puxar os valores dos campos e ai sim envia-lo após a montagem. Você pode montar um código `for` no java script fazendo um `push` em uma lista e depois passar ela no `data` da requisição.

Comment: Bom dia Victor, pesquisei mais sobre sua sugestão e fiquei em duvida de como capturar os valores da minha lista e montar o array no ajax. Não tenho experiencia com web, você poderia dar um exemplo de como fazer isso? Obrigado!

Comment: Aqui nesse tópico ensinam como você pode criar seu array de objetos, logo em seguinda  passe no data dando um JSON.stringify(). https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225013/como-criar-array-de-objetos-em-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Os valores estão indo pro `model` desatualizados pois na montagem do código da página pelo `Razor` está sendo passado `model` daquele momento (Com os valores iniciais). Para envia-los para o controller através do *ajax*, recomendo montar um objeto que vai puxar os valores dos campos e ai sim envia-lo após a montagem. Você pode montar um código for no javascript fazendo um `push` em uma lista e depois passar ela no `data` da requisição.

Aqui nesse tópico ensinam como você pode criar seu array de objetos, logo em seguinda passe no data dando um JSON.stringify().

> [Como criar array de objetos em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225013/como-criar-array-de-objetos-em-javascript)

Comment: Bom dia victor! Na verdade eu preciso de duas listas que estão no model, então eu teria que enviar dois arrays?. Eu vi o exemplo de como montar o array, mas não sei como referenciar minha lista para pegar os valores e montar o array. Obrigado

Comment: Olá! consegui resolver meu problema usando esse site como referencia [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Convert-HTML-Table-data-to-JSON-and-send-to-Controller-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx). Agradeço a ajuda de todos!